# If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact and $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ then $A\times \{x\}$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I'm stuck in this part of the Heine Borel proof. Could you help me please? I'm trying to prove it using the fact that a compact set is such that given a open cover we can extract a finite subcover. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that compactness is a topological property (i.e. preserved under homeomorphisms)? Can you find a homeomorphism between $A$ and $A \times \{ x \}$?  That's all you need.

Comment: One option: choose your favorite definition of compactness. Assume $A \times \{x\}$ is not compact. Then this implies that something (depending on your chosen definition of compactness) exists. Translate this into saying that something (...) in $A$ exists that would imply that $A$ is not compact.

Comment: Your statement is not the Heine Borel theorem. Rather, it is a very special case of Tikhonov's theorem: if $A \subset \mathbb R^N$ and $B \subset \mathbb R^M$ are compact, then $A \times B \subset \mathbb R^{N+M}$ is compact. Heine Borel theorem states that $A \subset \mathbb R^N$ is compact iff $A$ is closed and bounded.

Comment: Thank you. Is done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $\Theta$ be an open cover for $A \times \lbrace \mathbf x \rbrace.$ We need to show that there are finitely many open sets in $\Theta$ that cover $A.$ For each $(\mathbf a, \mathbf x) \in A \times \lbrace \mathbf x \rbrace,$ note that $(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)  \in \theta_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)} \in \Theta$ for some open set $\theta_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)}.$ Therefore, there are open rectangles $U_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)} \subset \mathbb R^N$ and $V_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)} \subset \mathbb R^M$ with $\mathbf a \in U_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)}$ and $\mathbf x \in V_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)}$ and $U_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)} \times V_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)} \subset \theta_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)}.$ (Why ?) Then, can you deduce something about the constructed collection of rectangles $\lbrace U_{(\mathbf a, \mathbf x)} \rbrace_{\mathbf a \in A}$ ? Finally, how can you deduce the desired claim ?

**Remark 1**: Once you prove the above result, you can then prove the following statement: if $A \subset \mathbb R^N$ is compact and $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^M$ and if $\Theta$ is an open cover for $A \times \lbrace \mathbf x \rbrace,$ then there is an open set $W_{\mathbf x} \subset \mathbb R^M$ with $\mathbf x \in W_{\mathbf x}$ such that $\Theta$ finitely covers $A \times W_\mathbf x.$

**Remark 2**: Once you put everything together, then you can prove *Tikhonov's theorem*: if $A \subset \mathbb R^N$ is compact and $B \subset \mathbb R^M$ is compact, then $A \times B \subset \mathbb R^{N+M}$ is compact.

Comment: This is the key I didn't have: Identify $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$, then, $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ is open if and only if for each $(x, y)\in A$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n, y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ there exist open sets $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n, V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ with $x\in U, y\in V$, such that $U\times V\subseteq A$. Thank you so much @Vivek Kaushik.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach: suppose $\mathscr A$ is an open cover of $A\times \{x\}.$ Since basis elements in the product topology of $\mathbb R^n \times \{x\}$ are of the form $B\times \{x\}$ for a basis element $B\in \tau_{\mathbb R^n}$, an arbitrary element of $\mathscr A$ is of the form $U\times \{x\},\ U$ open in $\mathbb R^n.$ And since the first projection $\pi$ is an open map, $\{\pi(U):U\in \mathscr A\}$ is an open cover of $A,$ from which we can  extract a finite subcover $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n.$ Then $\{U_i\times \{x\}\}_{i=1}^n$ is a finite subcover of $\mathscr A.$

Comment: Thank you, problem solved.